# Generate Backface of a mesh in Blender

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, culling

I am using my blender objects in unity. Unity is culling the backfaces.

So I wanted to generate the backfaces as seperate polys from blender itself. I can do it by duplicating the mesh itself but is there any way to do it through a modifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [solidify modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Solidify) will generate a second surface parallel to the original.

If you want the new surface as a separate object, you can disable 'Fill Rim', then when you apply the modifier the mesh will be two disconnected parts. In edit mode Press <kbd>L</kbd> to select linked vertices which you can separate by selection <kbd>P</kbd> to move them to a second object.

Comment: Tried to close the back of a mesh from a 3D-scan where I couldn't capture the whole object and after lots of googling and frustration I finally found your answer from years ago that did the trick. Thank you!